# Are groovy list literals ArrayLists or LinkedLists?

Tags: groovy

Are groovy's literal lists e.g. `['foo','bar','baz']` backed by an ArrayList (dynamic array), or a LinkedList? There are [performance benefits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Performance) when using one instead of the other in different situations.

Related: is there a way I can find out the type of a variable at runtime in groovy, similar to JavaScript's `typeof` operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless specified it creates it as an ArrayList.  You can specify a linked list by `def myList = [] as LinkedList` or by instantiating directly `def myLinkedList = new LinkedList()`

`myList.getClass().name` will tell you the type.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the class on the object to see what it is:

```
groovy:000> [].class
===> class java.util.ArrayList
```

Check its type with `instanceof`, just like in Java:

```
groovy:000> [] instanceof ArrayList
===> true
```

which tells you if the object is an ArrayList or a subclass of ArrayList.

Or test its class:

```
groovy:000> [].class == ArrayList
===> true
```

which tells you if the concrete class of the object is ArrayList.